# How to have video-js markers with duration

Tags: google-maps-markers, video.js

I am using the video-js and video-js markers for a video on a webpage. I am trying to define markers that appear in the player seekable player, but I am only able to get a single point for the video. My research has pointed me to just use the duration field, but still it is not setting the markers to be able to see visually on the seekbar the in and out point of the marker. What am I missing?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://awakenstudios.net/oneclip/videoplayer/css/video-js.min.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://awakenstudios.net/oneclip/videoplayer/css/videojs.markers.min.css"/>
 <script src="https://awakenstudios.net/oneclip/videoplayer/js/video.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://awakenstudios.net/oneclip/videoplayer/js/videojs-markers.min.js"></script>
      <video 
        id="example_video_1" 
        class="video-js vjs-default-skin viewer"
        controls 
        preload="auto" 
        autoplay
        width="640" 
        height="360"
        data-setup='{"width": 640, "height": 360}'>
      <source src="...904734493.mp4" type='video/mp4' />        
    </video>
 <style>


.video-js .vjs-marker .vjs-marker-text {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
     .marker2{    background-color: yellow;  }
</style>

    <script>
  var player = videojs('example_video_1');
  
  player.markers({
  markers: [
    {
      time: 10,
      end: 20,
      text: 'Marker 1',
      overlayText: '10s - 20s',
      class: 'marker1'
    },
    {
      time: 30,
      end: 40,
      text: 'Marker 2',
      overlayText: '30s - 40s',
      class: 'marker2'
    }
  ]
});
    
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Duration field works for me - you are not using it in the example above?

```
{
        time: 10,
        text: "text",
        class: "class-name",
        duration: 10,
}
```